# c++: нулевое значение std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, таймер, std-chrono

Подскажите как можно выставить пустое/нулевое значение для типа

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>
```

Мне необходимо отслеживать несколько таймеров у которых могут быть сброшены значения счетчиков.

Сейчас для этой цели использую дополнительную переменную, но хотелось бы что-то подобное

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> value = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
// ...
if (value != 0)
{
    //...
    value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать конструктор по-умолчанию.

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> t;
t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
t = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>();
```

или просто `t = {};`

Проверять `t.time_since_epoch().count()`.